# Pi 4B not booting

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, boot-issues, bootloader

I bought my **Raspberry Pi 4B with 1GB RAM** last year, and I recently turned it on and found this error(?) screen.

[image: Text]

I can't seem to find the issue:

1. I already reset the EEPROM
2. I tried a different SDCard

Please Help!!!
It said with a different card `sdcard not found`

Comment: Did you use the Pi Imager to write Raspberry Pi OS to the sd card? https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/

Comment: Did you check the image downloaded correctly?  I'm old fashioned and like to download a file, check that the sha256 value matches then flash with Etcher using the verify option

Comment: You wrote "*sdcard not found*" - this is wrong. The screen copy tells us: "*SD: card detected 0002544d5341303847213be72bd89106*".

Comment: the message mostly points that SD doesn't contains properly made `/boot` drive for raspbberry. You need to flash drive with the compatible image